# Rancher Cluster `cloud_provider` YAML: How to use Active Directory Domain Credentials (i.e. user name with back slash) in YAML?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, vsphere, rancher

I'm attempting to put my AD domain credentials into the YAML config file created by rancher so that I may use vSphere storage within Rancher / Kubernetes, however, I'm running into an issue with the formatting of the `virtual_center` config portion:

```
(...)
    virtual_center:
        <IP>:
            (...)
            user: "DOMAIN/username"
            password: <PASSWORD>
```

The cluster doesn't seem to like a backslash (or two backslashes including the escape character), and it also doesn't seem to like a forward slash.

How should I enter my domain credentials in here?

**EDIT**

nvm, i figured it out.

JK, answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution is to use a `user@domain.site.local` format rather than a `DOMAIN\user` format.

See: 
https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/16371